# How to remove the "default" child object in webpack "var" build output

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I am using webpack to build my code.

Here's my output config.

```
{
    library: 'Foo',
    libraryTarget: 'var',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'foo.js'
}
```

This technique successfully builds the code to a browser friendly version. However, there's this "default" child object being created in the main output object of the built code.

In order to access the main constructor of the code, I need to `Foo.default` instead of just `Foo()`.

Comment: What kind of export statement did you used at the foo.js file?

Comment: @felixmosh I was using `export default class ...`

Comment: So this is the reason for the default property, if you just export the class, you will get the Foo class.

Comment: Wut? Really? Damn.

Comment: I tried it, but when I used the object instance like `var foo = new Foo()` I get this error. `Uncaught TypeError: Tutor is not a constructor` @felixmosh

Comment: How did you imported it?

Comment: Same issue can't get rid of the `.default`